# How close is the history state to the ground state in the Kitaev clock construction?

Tags: complexity-theory, hamiltonian-simulation, qma

Consider a standard circuit to Hamiltonian reduction in QMA. For example, refer [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Evazirani/s07quantum/notes/qma.pdf) (Vazirani's lecture notes) or page 235 of [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.3916) (survey by Gharibian et al).

The history state of the Kitaev clock Hamiltonian $H$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
 |\psi_{\text{history}}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{T + 1}} \sum_{i = 0}^{T} V_{i} V_{i - 1} \cdots V_{1} |00 \cdots 0 \rangle |\psi\rangle |i\rangle_{\text{clock}},
\end{equation}
where $V = V_{T} V_{T-1}\cdots V_{1}$ is the circuit that the QMA verifier, and $|\psi\rangle$ is the state sent by the prover. Note that $|\psi_{\text{history}}\rangle$ is not the ground state of $H$. But how close is it to the ground state?

In other words, if $|\psi_{\text{ground}}\rangle$ is the ground state of the Kitaev clock Hamiltonian $H$, I am trying to find

\begin{equation}
|| |\psi_{\text{ground}}\rangle - |\psi_{\text{history}}\rangle ||.
\end{equation}